# Using subset on a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Im working on a problem that needs me to subset my data and im currently using subset() in order to do so but im having trouble with the syntax. Below is the problem that I am working through and my current code.

Problem:

Some product IDs had 0 votes, which would result in an error if we tried to take the log.  Subset the variables max.votes and number.of.reviews (or whatever you called them) to only those values corresponding to products with 1 or more votes.

Code:

```
#Use tapply to find max votes recieved by product reviews


max.votes=tapply(`Number of Votes`, `Product ID`, max,na.rm=TRUE)


#Count number of reviews for each product ID

Reviews.per.product=tapply(`Product ID`,`Product ID`,length)



#1i

#Make a scatter plot of max votes as a function of number of reviews

plot(max.votes~Reviews.per.product)

#There is no apparent trend that I am able to pick out from the scatter plot.


#1J

#Create subsets with 0's removed
foods_max_votes_subset = finefoods.dataframe[finefoods.dataframe$Nu >= 1, ]
subset.max.votes=subset(max.votes,max.votes>=1)


subset.Reviews.per.product=subset(Reviews.per.product,max.votes>=1)
```

Updated code:

```
NotZero = which( max.votes >= 1 )
max.votes.subset.test = max.votes[ NotZero ]
Reviews.per.product.subset.test = Reviews.per.product[NotZero]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this a number of ways:

with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

foods_max_votes_subset  <- finefoods.dataframe %>%
    filter(Reviews.per.product >= 1,
           max.votes >= 1)
```

base R:

```
foods_max_votes_subset  <- finefoods.dataframe[(finefoods.dataframe$Reviews.per.product >= 1 & finefoods.dataframe$max.votes >= 1),]
```

Also noticed your code looks a lot like python. you tagged this post as python and r. Which are you coding in?

Comment: Im coding in R. It somehow accidentally tagged both of them on accident. Currently the way I have done this is that max.votes and Reviews per product are broken down by product ID and then the associated value either max.votes or Reviews per product.

Comment: updated the code. I'm not 100% though what you're saying. If you could provide a reproducible example by listing a handful of rows of code and code it into a dataframe, I could pull it out and play with it.

Comment: I added code to above to create subset where votes are greater than 1 and then used that on the other variable. My code for that is above.

Comment: I'm even more confused than I was before haha. Is your data in a dataframe?
use this code (dummy data) and then try to explain what you're trying to do. I'm assuming you're trying to count the number of product reviews, and then the max votes, but you want to do all of that with the 0 votes lines removed, right?
`df <- data.frame(prod_id = sample(paste0("prod_", 1:10), 100, replace = TRUE), votes = sample(0:20, 100, replace = TRUE))`